# How to make an image clickable and execute function?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm simply trying to make an image clickable and execute function. 
Here is my code:

```
<button class="button button-stable button-clear" on-click="myFunction()">
<img src="image.png" >
</button>
```

But the function is not executing on the click event.

Comment: The correct attribute is `onclick`.  Or, in angular, `ng-click`, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With angular you should use `ng-click`.

try `ng-click="myFunction()"`

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
<img src="image.png" ng-click="myFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try put `ng-click` in `<img>`

For example

```
<img class="button " ng-src="{{i.imagem}}" ng-click="myFunction($index)"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is event binding in Angular. [Read more about this from Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

```
<img [src]="yourVariable" (click)="yourFunction()">
```

Comment: It's angular(io) not angularjs.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to. With a little extra markup you can do this.

- Wrap image in label
- set for to a hidden button id
- run js on button click

Doing this will be a more **accessible** solution for **people with disabilities**.
Use this html.

```
<!--html-->
<label for="image-click">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" />
</label>
<button id="image-click" 
  onclick="myFunction()" 
  class="visuallyhidden">
  Click to run image
</button>
```

And add some css.

```
//css
.visuallyhidden {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is a codepen that shows how - http://codepen.io/bitlinguist/pen/bEJvoz

You can just as easily adopt this approach with angular directives.

Comment: Overly complex solution to this problem. He's using Angular. Angular has a built-in feature for this. Adding CSS, Jquery, etc. is overkill.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Fair enough, but you should read and you will see that the jQuery is only for the function to write to body. Simplified the illustration. All you need is the markup and css. Visuallyhidden is commonly part of sass frameworks, and pointer is usually set on labels. label["for"] can be used to specify. And the markup is accessible. I am not sure however if an alt tag is accessible enough for clickable images or if angular is using something to solve this issue.

Anyway, thanks for the feedback. Ill update the answer without jquery.